# Bootstrap Modal blacking the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal and sometimes after I close this modal, the window (body) keeps in a gray background... (same color as the modal's open background)

PS: In my application, i'm using a navbar too, and everytime I change the nav tab and then click on the button to open the modal, the modal's background gets darker than it was before!!

Does anybody here knows what can I do to have a normal background's modal? And when I close it, make it come back to the normal color?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide a sandboxed example of the issue and then we can help debug.

Comment: Well, something interesting I found out is that sometimes the code has two lines of "<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>" and sometimes it has four, so it gets darker... Is there a waya to fix it?

Comment: It would be best if you could provide an example in jsfiddle. It sounds like a js error is happening when you close the modal, causing the backdrop not be properly removed. Can you check the console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

@peterdotjs,

I'm a new developer, so I don't know yet how to check the console for errors...

But I found out the solution, I just added `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` on the closing jQuery method, which is now like:

```js
$("#btn").click(
    function() {
        $('#myModalClient').modal('hide');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();   //it removes the modal back-drop
    }
);
```